# Thread.sleep() isn't pausing execution

Tags: java, multithreading, vaadin, sleep, thread-sleep

I'm trying to limit attempts of a process in a loop to 60 seconds by sleeping for 3,000ms per loop with 20 attempts. Calling Thread.sleep() isn't actually pausing execution in the thread that's running and instead, all 20 attempts happen rapidly in succession.

```
private void pollWebServiceForToken() {
    final int pollInterval = 3000;
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int attempts = 0;
            int maxAttempts = 60;
            String token;
            do {
                token = requestToken(exchangeCode);
                if (token.contains(FAILED)) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(pollingInterval);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        this.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
                attempts++;
            } while (token.toLowerCase().contains(FAILED) && attempts < maxAttempts && !cancelled);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Since this is all happening inside of a Vaadin application, I'm assuming the wrong Thread is being put to sleep but I'm not sure how to target a specific thread for sleeping.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the InterruptedException happening?

Comment: No, it's running through all 20 attempts almost instantly = /

Comment: What exactly is the point of interrupting the current thread in an `InterruptedException` catch-handler?

Comment: Generally when you see an `InterruptedException` in a thread you should break out of any processing and allow the thread to terminate. Adding a `break;` at the end of your `catch` block would help. Not related to your problem, just a best-practice.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is the first time I've had to thread anything so there are still nuances I need to understand =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the code inside the if is being run? The condition on the while is different (+toLowerCase). `Thread.sleep()` always causes the current thread to sleep.

Comment: Yikes, that's embarrassing. Thanks for saving me another hour for such a silly oversight!